# How to adjust brightness and prevent from turning off screen on WatchOS programmatically?

Tags: swift, watchos

I try to make WatchOS QR code payment app on swift now.

But I can't find any clues of preventing screen from turning off and adjusting brightness programmatically.

There are few question in stackoverflow, but there are quite old questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't.....